# Capturing a delimiter that isn't in between single quotes

Tags: regex

Like the question says, is it possible to use a single Regex string to get a delimiter that isn't in between some quotes?

For example, I want to split this string with the delimiter `&`:

```
"example=3&testing='f&tmp'"
```

should produce

```
["example=3", "testing='f&tmp'"]
```

Essentially, things inside single quotes (`' '`) should remain untouched.

I found out how to get things within quotes with expression: `(?:'.*?')`

The closest I could get to a tangible solution was: `(.[^']&[^'])`

Comment: What programming language the regex is used in?

Comment: That looks like a URL query string? An ampersand would not be represented literally in this form, and you can't "wrap" parameters in quotes like that to avoid the problem. Instead, the ampersand [would be escaped as `%26`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP).

Comment: In other words, I would expect the string to look like: `"example=3&testing=f%26tmp"`.

Comment: Also depending on the programming language you are using (???) there is probably a built-in standard library function to parse URLs / URL query strings, without having to do it yourself via string splitting and/or regex.

Comment: I'm planning to use native Java, specifically String.split(regex). This isn't a URL string, but I see the similarity, and could probably get away by using the URL object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an easy task for a `String#split`, but is quite a feasible task for `Matcher#find` if you use

```java
[^&\s=]+=(?:'[^']*'|[^\s&]*)
```

(see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y0L362/1/)) and [this Java code](https://ideone.com/ZIwVD1):

```java
String text = "example=3&testing='f&tmp'";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^&\\s=]+=(?:'[^']*'|[^\\s&]*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    res.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(res);
// => [example=3, testing='f&tmp']
```

*Details*

- `[^&\s=]+` - one or more chars other than `&`, `=` and whitespace
- `=`  - a `=` char
- `(?:'[^']*'|[^\s&]*)` - a non-capturing group matching either `'`, zero or more chars other than `'` and then a `'`, or zero or more chars other than whitespace and `&`.

Comment: Interesting, I thought `String::split` was capable seeing as its underlying code was just using a Regex compiler, but this will do just fine. Thank you!

Comment: @AnishGovind If you use `text.split("&(?![^']*'[^']*(?:'[^']*'[^']*)*$)")` it will probably work, but the pattern is a convoluted one, it is one of the worst (=inefficient) regex constructs.